# Why does data get assigned without an extra copy being created, in an initialization list?

Tags: c++, initialization-list

[Parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) explains initialization lists well, but does not explain **why** an extra copy of a variable is created before assignment in the ctor body, but no extra copy is created when assigned through an initialization list.
I've even come across advice of using ++i instead of i++ because the former avoids creation of a temporary i before assignment. Is it the same for POD's assigned in a ctor body? A temp variable gets created before the assignment happens?

To put it another way, why does the compiler need to create an extra copy of a variable? Why can't it just assign the variable directly?
**Why?**

Comment: as for ++i vs i++, modern compilers generally optimize i++ to be equivalent to ++i in cases where that is possible, but the difference is that i++ has to generate a temporary (the original value of i) that is used in the statement being evaluated.  thus i++ is the "post-increment" operator; it doesn't increment the value until after the original value is taken. i generally use ++i except in the rare case that i'm willing to use i++ as part of a larger statement.  modifying a variable while using it in a larger statement can cause some obscure errors that are easy to miss on a scan through.

Comment: Your title shows a fundamental misunderstanding. Data does *not* get **assigned** in the initialization list, it gets **initialized**.

Comment: @FredOverflow, if the second line of your comment was written as an answer, I'd have selected it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
struct C { 
    C() { /* construct the object */ }
};

struct X {
    C member;

    X() { member = C(); }
};
```

The `X()` constructor is the same as if you had said:

```
X() : member() { member = C(); }
```

First, the `C` constructor is called to construct the `member` data member.  Then the body of `X` is executed, a second, temporary `C` object is created and assigned to `member`, then the temporary is destroyed.

---

Note that this is only the case for types that are initialized automatically.  If `member` was of type `int` or of a POD class type (as examples), it would be uninitalized when the body of the `X` constructor is entered.

For such types it doesn't really matter from a performance standpoint whether you initialize the data member in the initialization list or assign to the data member in the body of the constructor; the difference is entirely stylistic.  Where possible, the initialization list should still be preferred for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was "why?". Why is the extra temporary `C` object created? Why can't the assignment to `member` be done by the first call to `C`'s constructor? Besides, does this kind of temporary variable creation happen even for POD's?

Comment: "Why can't the assignment to member be done by the first call to C's constructor?"  If that were the case, assignment in constructors would be special and would require an exception to the usual assignment rules.  The last thing C++ needs is more special cases and extra rules.

Comment: Ok so I guess it's the "assignment rules" that I'm looking for. I can't seem to figure out why a temporary copy needs to be made before assignment. From section 3.10 of the standard, all I could figure out was that "that's just the way it's done in C++". Only the creator would know why :)

Answer (score 2):

To address your first question specifically regarding the copy (without touching on "++i" vs "i++"):

The constructor is a function, and it has parameters. These parameters are copies of the variables passed as parameters (unless passing by reference is used). You can now manipulate this copy or do anything else with it. Then when you assign, you take this copy of the parameter (possibility manipulated) and assign it to the member variable. When you use an initialization list, the compiler can optimize the assignment immediately without this copy, as you will not be using it for anything but the initialization (and cannot modify it before assigning it to the member variable).

Comment: But the use of initialization list is encouraged even when when the variable is passed as a `const` reference, right? Like in the copy ctor. I feel the reason is something else.

Answer (score 2):

> why an extra copy of a variable is created before assignment in the
>   ctor body, but no extra copy is created when assigned through an
>   initialization list.

Because assignment follows initialization. In other words, assignment is optional, but initialization is mandatory. You may not notice much difference for PODs. But the same holds true for user defined data types.

> advice of using ++i instead of i++

Again for PODs it doesn't matter much. But for user defined classes, `i++` does create a temporary copy. So it's better to use `++i`.

```
struct A {
  A operator ++ (int)  // example of i++
  {
    A temp = *this;
    this->value ++;
    return temp;    // makes 2 copies "temp" and return value
  }
  A& operator ++ ()  // example of ++i
  {
    this->value ++;
    return *this;  // no copy
  }
};
```

Comment: Initialization is not mandatory for all types.  `int x; // x is not initialized.`

Comment: @James, Some compiler does initialize `int`. However, I have mentioned `You may not notice much difference for PODs. `